# Command line data loader error in latest version during encrypting key

Tags: apex, data-loader, commandline

I am using latest version of command line data loader (V36).I am trying to encrypt key using below command in command line.

```
D:\Salesforce.com\bin>encrypt.bat -g anystring
```

But it throws me error saying "is was unexpected at this time."
Meanwhile i checked using previous version apex data loader it is not throwing any error and i am able to encrypt text using same above command.What could be issue ?

Comment: I got it what was the issue.In new data loader encrypt.bat & process.bat file has been changed and now these files uses environmental variable "JAVA_HOME".So we need to create a similar environmental variable and add java/bin path in that variable

Comment: I am setting new environment variable "JAVA_HOME" with directory in which jre has been installed.But still it not working.There are major changes in batch file for encryption and process in old(version 35) and new(version 36) data loader version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you can run command line data loader successfully using below encrypt.bat & process.bat file.This was happening because they have used (JRE) and () brackets are part of shell scripting.So just replace (JRE) with () and it will work fine.

Updated and working encrypt.bat file:

```
@echo off

IF "%JAVA_HOME%" == "" (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dataloader-36.0.0-java-home.exe') do (
        IF EXIST "%%i" (
            set JAVA_HOME=%%i
        ) ELSE (
            echo %%i
        )
    )
)

IF "%JAVA_HOME%" == "" (
    echo To run encrypt.bat, set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the directory where the Java Runtime Environment JRE is installed.
) ELSE (
    IF NOT EXIST "%JAVA_HOME%" (
        echo We couldn't find the Java Runtime Environment JRE in directory %JAVA_HOME%. To run process.bat, set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the directory where the JRE is installed.
    ) ELSE (
        "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java"  -cp ..\dataloader-36.0.0-uber.jar com.salesforce.dataloader.security.EncryptionUtil %*
    )
)
```

Updated and working process.bat file:

```
   @echo off
if not [%1]==[] goto run
echo.
echo Usage: process ^<configuration directory^> ^[process name^]
echo.
echo      configuration directory -- directory that contains configuration files,
echo          i.e. config.properties, process-conf.xml, database-conf.xml
echo.
echo      process name -- optional name of a batch process bean in process-conf.xml,
echo          for example:
echo.
echo              process ../myconfigdir AccountInsert
echo.
echo          If process name is not specified, the parameter values from config.properties
echo          will be used to run the process instead of process-conf.xml,
echo          for example:
echo.
echo              process ../myconfigdir
echo.

goto end

:run
set PROCESS_OPTION=
if not [%2]==[] set PROCESS_OPTION=process.name=%2


IF "%JAVA_HOME%" == "" (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dataloader-36.0.0-java-home.exe') do (
        IF EXIST "%%i" (
            set JAVA_HOME=%%i
        ) ELSE (
            echo %%i
        )
    )
)

IF "%JAVA_HOME%" == "" (
    echo To run process.bat, set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the directory where the Java Runtime Environment JRE is installed.
) ELSE (
    IF NOT EXIST "%JAVA_HOME%" (
        echo We couldn't find the Java Runtime Environment JRE in directory %JAVA_HOME%. To run process.bat, set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the directory where the JRE is installed.
    ) ELSE (
        "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -cp ..\dataloader-36.0.0-uber.jar -Dsalesforce.config.dir=%1 com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner %PROCESS_OPTION%
    )
)

:end
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.  Running it manually from the command line works.  Change into the main directory where Data Loader is installed (not the bin directory, in my case it's "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader"), and try this:

java -cp dataloader-36.0.0-uber.jar com.salesforce.dataloader.security.EncryptionUtil

That's effectively java followed by three parameters.

I suspect the problem is related to the new .bat file, and the fact that we have spaces in our directory names.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes problem is in new .bat file.I dont know how the unit testing salesforce has done.This is a major bug.I am trying to set JAVA_HOME path inside bat file now ,hope it works.

Comment: I got the issue.There is issue with encrypt.bat & process.bat file.echo statement is containing some special character and some reserved keywords.So please make echo statement as simple.Save it and close command prompt and open new command prompt.You also need to set JAVA_HOME environmental variable on your local machine.This will contains installed directory of JDK. New apex data loader works with Java 8.